# Need to present the nodes of a binary search tree through an array in Java. How do I do that?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

It's for homework for my Data Structures class, and it's in Java.

I have to make this little game sort of thing; the world is made up of a graph, and some nodes hold items that, when found, will be added to the user's inventory, which is a binary search tree. (It has to be a binary search tree, or else this would be much easier.) I have most of it figured out, but I need the user to be able to see and access the contents of the inventory tree thing. The binary tree node class I'm provided has an `inorderPrint()` method that uses recursion to print everything out, but that only helps for showing them the contents, not giving them an easy way to access them. I want to have a method that returns an array of binary search tree nodes so I can do something like this in main...

```
int i = 0;
int choice;
System.out.println("# - Item\tPoints"); //Will appear as # - Item     Points
for (BTNode node : inventory.treeAsArray()) {
    System.out.printf("%d - %s\t%d\n", i, node.getData().getName(),
                      node.getData().getPoints()); //example: 1 - Poo    100
    i++;
}

System.out.println("Select the number of the item you want to remove: ");
choice = keyboard.nextInt();
```

And then I'd loop through the array again and remove the item that corresponds with the number the user inputs. I don't know how I can write a method that returns the contents of a binary search tree in the form of an array, though. That's my main problem. I can't really find an algorithm for it in my textbook.

Comment: Create an array or list the size of the tree. Iterate over the tree and adding the elements in order.

Comment: normally, an array representation of a tree is a heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was to do this I would probably just pass an array to all of the node in order.

```
public ArrayList<BTNode> treeAsArray() {
    ArrayList<BTNode> list = new ArrayList<BTNode>();
    root.buildListInorder(list);
    return list;
}
```

and then have

```
private void buildListInorder(ArrayList<BTNode> list) {
    buildListInorder(this.left);
    list.add(this);
    buildListInorder(this.right);
}
```

You would need to add proper checks but that is a basic outline of the code needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<BTNode> treeAsArray() {
     return treeAsArray(this.root, new ArrayList<BTNode>());
}

private List<BTNode> treeAsArray(BTNode root, List<BTNode> array) {
     if (root == null)
         return array;

     treeAsArray(root->getLeftNode(), array);
     array.add(root);
     treeAsArray(root->getRightNode(), array);

     return array;
}
```